# MvvmCross binding to custom table cell in a storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm developing an app with MvvmCross which uses storyboards for the UI. Instead of using XIB files for my table cells like in the kitten example from Stuart, creating the cells in the storyboard. Everything works ok, the cells are being created but the for some reason I get a

```
MvxBind:Warning: 11.57 Failed to create target binding for binding Text for Title
```

error. There are three labels one image and a button on the cell prototype but I am only binding the labels at the moment (Title, Description and Date). The application works fine but the cells appear empty, I even added some checkmarks and they show up ok. Upon further digging I found out that my labels are null and that if I add a new label from code it works ok and it shows up

here is the code:

the TableViewController

```
partial class CreateView : MvxTableViewController
{
    public CreateView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(TableView, typeof(CreateTableCellView), CreateTableCellView.Key);
        TableView.Source = source;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CreateView, CreateViewModel>();

        set.Bind(source).For(s => s.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.CreatedItems);

        set.Apply();

        TableView.ReloadData();
    }
}
```

the TableViewCell

```
partial class CreateTableCellView : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("CreateCell");

    private UILabel _label;

    public CreateTableCellView(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        //_imageViewLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => this.imgThumb);

        _label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, 44));
        _label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        _label.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        Add(_label);

        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CreateTableCellView, CreateModel>();

            // the label added in code works fine
            set.Bind(_label).To(vm => vm.Title);
            // the lables below are null
            set.Bind(lblTitle).To(vm => vm.Title);
            set.Bind(lblDescripton).To(vm => vm.Descripton);
            set.Bind(lblDate).To(vm => vm.Date);
            //set.Bind(_imageViewLoader).To(vm => vm.ThumbImage);

            set.Apply();
        });
    }
}
```

the TableViewCell designer

```
[Register ("CreateTableCellView")]
partial class CreateTableCellView
{
    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UIButton btnDelete { get; set; }

    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UIImageView imgThumb { get; set; }

    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UILabel lblDate { get; set; }

    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UILabel lblDescripton { get; set; }

    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UILabel lblTitle { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (btnDelete != null) {
            btnDelete.Dispose ();
            btnDelete = null;
        }
        if (imgThumb != null) {
            imgThumb.Dispose ();
            imgThumb = null;
        }
        if (lblDate != null) {
            lblDate.Dispose ();
            lblDate = null;
        }
        if (lblDescripton != null) {
            lblDescripton.Dispose ();
            lblDescripton = null;
        }
        if (lblTitle != null) {
            lblTitle.Dispose ();
            lblTitle = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why the elements from the prototype cell are null? I used the designer on all of the other controllers on the sotryboard and thy work perfectly, the only ones coming null are in the class for the TableViewCell.

Comment: This is a bit too much code at once. I would suggest either a) narrowing down the scope of your problem to the most relevant lines of code from each file, or b) breaking this into a few separate questions.

Comment: The hub of this question is that your designer properties are `null`. If you can identify what causes that - or identify a method that is called when they are not `null` then you can fix the problem. I don't have an answer. My advice is to focus on those nulls - that's just an iOS and/or Xamarin issue - a Xam expert might be able to help...

Comment: thank you @Stuart, I tried to override some methods (AwakeFromNib, PrepareForReuse, SubviewAdded) but in all of them the label objects are still null, any ideas on other methods to try ? At the moment I resorted to using incode created items but I would still like to get to the bottom of this problem, I'll ask the xamarin guys as well PS I also changed the code to use a MvxSimpleTableViewSource